# How to parameterize the locators in selenium page object model with TestNg or any other framework?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, parameter-passing, pageobjects

I need to automate two applications in which the navigation almost looks similar but the locators  (xpath,id etc.,) are difderent.So,I have created a project with TestNg in eclipse and able to run one testcase for one application.But to maintain code reusability, I wanted to parameterize the locators( eg: in one application it is "`//div[contains(text(),'abc')]`" whereas in the other application it is "`//div[contains(text(),'def')]`.Searched in google but nothing is helpful.

Please let me know your comments. Am okay to start a new framework where the locators can be **parameterised**.

Comment: share your code that you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Define all your locators in application like Excel,

The structure of Excel should be in a way that, the first row refers to key, the Second row refers to the locators for "application A", the third row refers to the locators for application B corresponding to the key. The structure of excel should be as below

[image]

Excel reader class should be row iterator, the first row serves as Key and corresponding row serves as values. first iteration row 1 and row 2 values are placed in key and value mapping in a hashmap and the execution will be on Application A.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to keep different packages for test and page(locators).

In the locator you can create java classes for different kind of pages that you have in your application, where you can keep our locators as per the pages(java class) and can create methods where you can parameterize them for reusability.

In the test class you'll have to just create objects of the pages(java class) so that you can use the methods

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case you can try to write a utility function like this:

```
public static String  setlocator(String param){
    String test = "//div[contains(text(),'" +param+"')]"; 
    return test;

 }
```

and call that function in your any application to get the locator.